# Query on Entity Framework Core not working?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

This query works on Entity Framework 6 but it is not working on Entity Framework Core.

Here is my query

```
var fva = (from sa in efEntities.SifDenomination
                           join sva in efEntities.FormValueDenomination on sa.IdDenomination equals sva.IdDenomination
                           join bba in efEntities.TreasuryDenomination on
                           new { sa.IdDenomination, sa.IdCurrency, PostNumber = ((int)76300),DateWork=new DateTime(2017,3,6), SifTreasury = ((short)1) } equals
                           new { bba.IdDenomination, bba.IdCurrency,  bba.PostNumber,bba.DateWork, bba.SifTreasury }
                           into gj
                           from bba in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           where sa.IdCurrency == "978" && sa.IdActive == 0
                           select new
                           {                                   
                               IdDenomination = sva.IdDenomination                                   
                           }
                 ).ToList();
```

Error message:

> The ORDER BY position number 76300 is out of range of the number of items in the select list. A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 4.

Comment: Any reason you are converting number 76300 to int ? You did it as part of resolving the issue?

Comment: Not sure why you are trying to set the value of join columns, instead of using where but maybe try `new { sa.IdDenomination, sa.IdCurrency, 76300,new DateTime(2017,3,6), 1 } equals`

Comment: @artm - I tried new { sa.IdDenomination, sa.IdCurrency, 76300,new DateTime(2017,3,6), 1 } equals and i get error Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members ... Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access. I can't put where sa.IdCurrrency == "978" && sa.IdActive == 0 && bba.PostNUmber=76300 && bba.DateWork== new DateTime(2017, 3, 6) && bba.FormTreasury==1 because I am not getting any rows and I must get 12 rows. ON clause and WHERE clause are different things. My main problem is as I said it works in EF6 and not in EFCore.

Comment: I think you'll need to look at the SQL query that EF6 and EF Core generates, compare them and log the problem with MS. http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/order-by-position-out-range/